# How to clean url to accept ending slash or not with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I clean URL
`http://localhost/mysitedirectory/contacts.php`

to look like both:

`http://localhost/mysitedirectory/contacts`

`http://localhost/mysitedirectory/contacts/`

I want this because a user may add the ending trailing slash or leave it so I want .htaccess to configure such that it works both ways.

I noticed when I add the `/` at the end of the `contacts` it says "OBJECT NOT FOUND"...Error 404

How do I make it work even if I add the slash or not?

this is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^contacts$ contacts.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: `^contacts/?$` - slash at the end, made optional by the following quantifier question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) answered in a comment section:

`^contacts/?$` - slash at the end, made optional by the following quantifier question mark.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^contacts$ contacts.php [L,QSA,NC]
> RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

The two `RewriteCond` directives (filesystem checks) are entirely superfluous and should be removed. (As are the `QSA` flags on the `RewriteRule` directives.)

However, instead of allowing both `/contacts` and `/contacts/` (strictly speaking two *different* URLs) resolve to the same content (which would necessitate the need for a `rel="canonical"` tag) you should externally redirect from one to the other (canonical) URL.

By the look of it, the URL *without* the trailing slash is canonical, so remove the trailing slash with an external redirect. The only thing to be careful of is that you should not remove the trailing slash from physical directories (which would ordinarily cause a redirect loop).

For example:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Canonical redirect to remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrites
RewriteRule ^contacts$ contacts.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,NC]
```

The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` directives makes `contacts`, `CONTACTS` and `CoNtAcTs` all resolve to the same content. (So the `rel="canonical"` tag is still required to resolve this ambiguity.)